# JQuery .hide() with no positioning lost?

Tags: jquery, css, hide

I have the following simple script to make an element of my webpage fade in as the page is loaded.

```
$('#box1').hide();
$('#box1').delay(300).fadeIn(500);
```

The problem I have is that when hidden, `#box1` takes up no space (due to its class being visible:none). How can I hide `#box1` so it doesn't disrupt other floated elements that depend on its presence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if that's possible in your case but you could just set the opacity of the element,

```
$('#box1').css('opacity':0);
```

then

```
$('#box1').delay(300).fadeTo(1,500);
```

Comment: jQuery's pretty adept at handling cross-browser opacity.

Comment: I did the same thing, just had to set the IE filter property in addition, jQuery handles the rest. +1

Answer (score 1):

Put `#box1` in a wrapper and give it a width and height. Now when you hide #box1, wrapper stay empty.

```
<div id="#wrapper">
  <div id="box1"></div>
</div>

#wrapper{
..
}
```

Comment: I'd rather avoid adding in html elements if possible. Isn't it possible to maybe add the style in css then start the fade immediately after removing the style?

Answer (score 0):

This code works without losing position and does not collapse.

(hide)

```
$("#name").animate({opacity:0});
```

(show)

```
$("#name").animate({opacity:1});
```

Answer (score -1):

JQuery's hidden is the equivalent of setting the display to none. This is the same currently as:

```
$('#box1').css({"display":"none"});
```

Instead try first setting the css class on the object to have a visibility of none. Something like:

```
$('#box1').css({"visibility":"hidden"});
```

Then

```
$('#box1').delay(300).fadeIn(500);
```